# How to convert my current large Mysql DB over to Rails 4.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a large Mysql db that I want to quickly use in a rails app, but I don't want to have to write all the db schemas for all the models I have to write..is there a quick way to have all the models and tables set up quickly?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, here's how:

1. Make sure you configured your database connection correctly in `config/database.yml`
2. Run `rake db:schema:dump`

Tip on the side: Run `rake -T db:schema` and you'll get a list of all available commands related to database schema tasks:

```
rake db:schema:cache:clear  # Clear a db/schema_cache.dump file
rake db:schema:cache:dump   # Create a db/schema_cache.dump file
rake db:schema:dump         # Create a db/schema.rb file that is portable against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load         # Load a schema.rb file into the database
```

Generating the models however is a different story, especially if your existing database does not follow the rails conventions' on naming.

There are some gems like [rmre](https://github.com/bosko/rmre) which are intended for exactly this, but it seems unmaintained.

If your legacy database is not a monster, you can quickly create the models yourself - the trick here is to not create any migrations i.e:

`rails g model YourModel --migration=false`

Then you have to adapt some key attributes like table name and primary key to ActiveRecord's naming convention which can be done as follows:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'a_legacy_table_name'
  self.primary_key = 'primary_key_column_name'

  belongs_to :other_model, 
    foreign_key: 'foreign_key_on_other_table'

  has_many :other_models, 
    foreign_key: 'foreign_key_in_this_table', 
    primary_key: 'primary_key_on_other_table'
end
```